# Install new software for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I tried to install the CDT plugin for Eclipse indigo. But when I press "Help->install new software" nothing is displaying. I don't know why this button doesn't work.

The eclipse's version: 3.5.2

Answer (score 1):

Go to Help ->Install New Software. Then in Work With, paste this link :-

http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/indigo.

Click Enter

4 Items will Apear. Check "CDT Main Features"

( Choose according your need )

Click Next and again Next. Then Accept the license and click Finish. It will start Installing

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that the button "Help->install new software" doesn't work. Ican't install nothing.

Comment: Please explain. What do you mean by doesn't work ? Is it not clickable ?

Comment: Start by checking you error log under Window -> Show View -> Error Log. See if you're getting any exception while trying to install new software.

Comment: Yes.
No dialog box and no window is displayed.

Comment: Delete the metadata folder in your workspace folder. Close eclipse first. If all else fails, try uninstalling and downloading the ADT bundle for latest version